# Question about mounting two LED strips in parallel, one properly and one reversed, and using a switch to switch between the two

Tags: led, led-strip

I work in a bar and we want to install UV lighting with UV LED strips. Currently, we have a simple circuit that consists of a 12V transformer and wires which go all around the bar, with regular white LED strips placed at key locations.

Now, buying another transformer and running another circuit would cost some money and also would be a lot of work, so I was wondering if we could reuse the circuit already in place, since the regular lighting and the UV lighting should never be used together at the same time.

The idea is to add next to each of the existing LED strips a new UV strip, then wire it in parallel with the existing wiring, but in reverse. Then, add a switch next to the transformer that reverses the polarity of the wires coming out of it.

This way, only one set of strips would be active at a time, and they can be easily switched, and the installation would be quite easy and cheap.

Would this work?

Also, if both sets of LED strips are about 60W each, and the transformer is 72W, it would not be overloaded, since the current that flows through the inactive LEDs is next to none, is that correct?

Comment: So, your looking to see what the reverse breakdown voltage of a typical 3 led + resistor circuit is.

Comment: @Passerby yeah, it seems so. But I also want to know if there is something wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: The overload issue is not an issue. If they do reverse breakdown, it will be a quick spike and dead led strips, so the current overload will only be for a few seconds at best. If the strips will survive a constant 12V reverse bias, thats debatable. You can get a small strip and test, or add a diode for reverse protection (one on each end, sized for 14V and how ever many amps as a precaution). A quick google search didn't provide any examples of people *using* strips this way, so you may be the first. It is a good thought though.

Comment: you imply that you have several (many ? ) strips of LED's. Adding to what Passerby has commented on,  are you sure the LED strips are all in series connection ?

Comment: @Passerby yeah, well, I have some background in low-level programming and you do stupid stuff like this all the time, reusing and refitting what you've already got... anyway, testing seems like a good idea, I suppose 24h should be enough. But I would like to know: if they survive, would the reverse current wear them down more quickly than if they were properly connected and left on?

Comment: @Marla yes, it is basically a long single strip cut in the appropriate locations and with connecting wires soldered on.

Comment: I just thought that LED strips that "go all around the bar" might be in series, and it sounded odd that 12 volts was sufficient.  I do agree with Passerby that if the white LED's can support the reverse voltage, you have a nice solution. Adding a diode in series with existing white LED strip is good idea to protect against reverse voltage overload. Use diode with UV strip too. Also, the reverse current will Not "wear down" the existing white LED's.

Comment: I was just thinking :  If your transformer is 12 volts AC (no internal rectifier), then the LED strip must have rectifier. If this is true, then reversing the transformer will still light the white LED's

Comment: @marla typical multiple "3 led + resistor" circuits in parallel type led strip.

Comment: thank you Passerby,  Guess I need to study up on "LED strips"

Comment: @marla our transformer supplies DC and our LEDs are DC.  

Just FYI, AC LEDs do exist, but they usually contain two parallel LEDs in one casing, each wired inversely with respect to each other. As the current alternates, only one of them is emitting light at any given moment but to the eye it looks like a constant light.

Comment: Why connect them in reverse at all? Why not just use the switch to change which of the two strips is in the circuit?

Comment: @NickJohnson well, there are many strips all around the bar. We would either have to have a separate switch for each one, which is silly, or make an entirely new different circuit, which involves drilling holes and threading cables through some uncomfortable locations, not to mention the cleanup afterwards. The whole idea is to reuse as much of the existing wiring as possible.

Answer (score 1):

better option is to work with 2 positive rails and shared negative, using a switch to choose which positive rail to turn on.
negative from leds goes directly to power supply, positive goes to switch.

- a two position switch (on-on)
- a three position switch (on-off-on)

  connect the power supply in the middle terminal, one positive going to each led rail on side terminals.

but you can do what you are thinking and reverse the voltage, just use a two or three position switch with double terminal and connect like the image (the motor there will be the leds).
about the supply, it's correct what you said, leds consumes no current in reverse.
[image]

Comment: OP is looking for a solution that doesn't require rewiring. They only have two conductor wire already in place.

Comment: did you read all the answer?
"but you can do what you are thinking and reverse the voltage, just use a two or three position switch with double terminal and connect like the image (the motor there will be the leds)."

Comment: Did you take reverse bias breakdown failure into account?